# Why do my references abide by different margins?

Tags: bibliographies, margins

I am currently experiencing a strange phenomenon, my references are indented differently (see screenshot below). I am writing in latex, using Overleaf. [image: References are following different margins]

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Show the part of code, please. Have You written something like that \href{some text} or You take information from another file?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Unfortunately, reliable psychics rarely, if ever, hang out on TeX.SE. To increase your chances that anyone will manage to diagnose the situation and come up with a cure, you would do well do provide a bit more information about how you create the bibliography. E.g., was the document created with LaTeX? If so, which document class do you employ? Which bibliography-related software tools do you employ, or do you create the bibliography entirely by hand? Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: It looks like you have an un-escaped URL which is starting math mode (thus producing lots of errors you are ignoring), and this somehow changes the margins.  Please show at least the two `Norges Bank` entries: that should give a clue on why one prints correctly and the other one doesn't

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. @PhelypeOleinik, you were correct, it initiated math mode, so by setting a \ before the "_" in the URL I was able to solve the problem.

@ Mico, thank you for the funny and constructive feedback. I would update accordingly, be it not for that the answer was found using the suggestion from @ Phelype Oleinik.

Answer (score 1):

The last reference for Norges Bank initiated math mode, which in turn skewed the allignment. By setting a \ before the "_" in the URL I was able to solve the problem.

Comment: That should not botch anything, did you remember to load the url er even better the xurl package?